# Fedena 3.0 CalendarDateSelect Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, fedena

I get this error in Fedena Calendar Date Select:

[image]

Although this js file already exists there.

Comment: As mentioned in the error message, make sure the `<%= javascript_include_tag :defaults %>` line is above `<%= calendar_date_select_includes %>`. The first line includes `prototype.js` and the second line includes calendar_date_select.  The first line may be slightly different on your app.

Comment: in which file shuld I change this, prototype.js?

Comment: Search the codebase to find where `calendar_date_select_includes` is.

Comment: Thanks Prakash for the reply, I didnt know who to find this and then what to do further, the simple I did is replace all the folers from backup folder and problem solved.

Comment: Is issue still there ?